# Searching in database not working | PHP HTML5 CSS MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm making an database driven site for a school project.
(Keep in mind I didn't stick to the copyright rules since it's a private website
which will be shut down after).

1: I've connected my database via a file named 'verbinding.php' (I'm Dutch, it would be 'connection.php' in English)

```
<?php
$verbinding = mysqli_connect('localhost','*********','**********','**********');
?>
```

2: I've made a file in which I have coded my database plus a form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" href="dieren.css" type="text/css" />
        <title> PO dierentuin </title>
    </head>
    <?php include 'verbinding.php'
    ?>
    
    <body>
<div id="zoekvenster">
    <p>Zoek door onze database als een varkentje met een heel goed neusje</p>
<form  method="post" action="zoeken.php"  id="zoekbox"> 
      Zoekwoord <input  type="text" name="zoekwoord"><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="categorie" value="animalnumber" id=Cat_1>Diernummer</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="categorie" value="species" id=Cat_2>Diersoort</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="categorie" value="stay" id=Cat_3>Verblijf</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="categorie" value="gender" id=Cat_4>Geslacht</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="categorie" value="place of birth" id=Cat_5>Nationaliteit</label><br>
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Zoeken"> 
</form>
</div>
<h2>All animals we have</h2>
<div id="inleiding">
<?php
  $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Dierentuin";
  $resultaat = mysqli_query($verbinding, $sqlquery);
  $queryResultaat = mysqli_num_rows($resultaat);
echo"
  <table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Animalnumber</th>
<th>Species</th>
<th>Race</th>
<th>Date of birth</th>
<th>Voeding</th>
<th>Stay</th>
<th>Mass</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Place of birth</th>
</tr>";

  if ($queryResultaat > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultaat)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Diernr']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Soort']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Ras']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Leeftijd']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Voeding']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Verblijf']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Gewicht_in_kg']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['M/V']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['Nationaliteit']."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
  } else {
      echo "Something went wrong";
  }
?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
        <footer>
        <p>This assignment was produced by Tieme and Marijn. 5VWO Marne College.</p>
        </footer>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

3: I also have the file 'zoeken.php' which will be referred as 'search.php' since zoeken is Dutch for search.

```
<?php
include('verbinding.php');
$zoekwoord = $_POST["zoekwoord"];
$categorie = $_POST["categorie"];
echo $categorie;
echo $zoekwoord;
$query = ("SELECT * FROM dierentuin WHERE $categorie is '$zoekwoord'");
$resultaat = mysqli_query($verbinding, $query);
  if ($resultaat > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultaat)) {
          echo ".'$row'['animalnumber'].";
          echo "Het werkt iniedergeval";
      }
  } else {
      echo "Something went wrong";
  }
```

Only, if you look in the form in the second file, you'll notice there is one textbox, and some radio's. Let's say, I fill in 'Congo' in place of birth, and check the radiobox Place of Birth, a query should be made in which I see only the animals born in the Congo.

If I do this on my website, no matter what I fill in it goes to the 'else' in the third file, and it says 'Something went wrong'

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection attack, also your query has error //WHERE $categorie is//  instead of 'is' use =

Answer (score 0):

("SELECT * FROM dierentuin WHERE $categorie is '$zoekwoord'");
You are comparing variable with variable.

It should be like that

SELECT * FROM dierentuin WHERE DBfieldname = "$variable_name" and   DBfieldname2 = "$variable_name2");

Comment: What do you mean by this? The DBfieldname is the $category since you select on what fieldname you search.

Comment: dbfileldsname mean your database field name, for which you want to search and use it without $.

Comment: Or you don't get me, or I don't get you. Could you explain how to change my codes? This is a link of what my form looks like [link](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2ywg2eq.jpg)